# Delete from a SQLite3 database with 2 (datetime) conditions

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a project, and I have a problem.

I want to delete some data from my database but with 2 conditions and my code isn't working. I want to store data of the last year and delete the rest.

```
#First get the actual year and month

date=datetime.datetime.now()
year=date.year
last_year=year-1
month=date.month

#for statement to delete the data from month 1 to actual month.

for x in range(1,month,1):
    x2=str(x).zfill(2)     #to transform an int 1 to an str '01'
    c.execute("DELETE FROM database WHERE strftime('%Y', Dates) = ? AND strftime('%m', Dates) = ?", (last_year,x2,))
    conn.commit()
c.close()
```

With one condition it works (with months or years), but when I want to use the 2 conditions it didn't work.

I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: What exactly does "isn't working" mean? Not deleting? Deleting the wrong things? Have you tested with both `%Y` and `%m` individually?

Comment: Not deleting.  individually the code works (I did something similar to delete data from previous year 2014, 2015, etc) but not with the 2 conditions.

Comment: How are the dates stored? Are they zero-padded for month?

Comment: The year comparison isn't working. You need to convert it to string on the python side.

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake. I needed to make the variable "Last_year" a string. Thanks glibdub !

Comment: Also, it should be `range(1, month+1)`, because range doesn't include the last value.